# How to use %>% in tidymodels in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidymodels

I am trying to split a dataset from tidymodels in R.

```
library(tidymodels)
data(Sacramento, package = "modeldata")
data_split <- initial_split(Sacramento, prop = 0.75, strata = price)
Sac_train <- training(data_split)
```

I want to describe the distribution of the training dataset, but the following error occurs.

```
Sac_train %>% 
      select(price) %>%
      summarize(min_sell_price = min(),
                max_sell_price = max(),
                mean_sell_price = mean(),
                sd_sell_price = sd())
# Error: In min() : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

However, the following code works.

```
Sac_train %>%
  summarize(min_sell_price = min(price),
            max_sell_price = max(price),
            mean_sell_price = mean(price),
            sd_sell_price = sd(price))
```

My question is: why `select(price)` is not working in the first example? Thanks.

Comment: `select(price)` only means your data has one column named `price`. Even if you put this one-column data into `summarize()`, it cannot pass this sole column into `min` or `max` automatically.

Comment: By the way, your problem has nothing to do with `tidymodels`. You should focus on the usage of `summarize` from `dplyr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data are a data frame, despite having only one column selected, you still need to tell R/dplyr what column you want to summarize.

In other words, it doesn't treat a single-column data frame as a vector that you can pass through a function - i.e.:

```
Sac_train.vec <- 1:25
mean(Sac_train.vec)
# [1] 13
```

will calculate the mean, whereas

```
Sac_train.df <- data.frame(price = 1:25)
mean(Sac_train.df)
```

throws an error.

In the special case of only one column, this may be more parsimonious code:

```
# Example Data
Sac_train <- data.frame(price = 1:25, col2 = LETTERS[1:25])

Sac_train %>% 
  select(price) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), 
                   list(min = min, max = max, mean = mean, sd = sd)))
```

Output:

```
#   price_min price_max price_mean price_sd
# 1         1        25         13 7.359801
```